# Automate DB restore from DB snapshot PostgreSQL AWS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, rds

I have a Postgres instance on AWS from which snapshots are taken daily. I have manually restored the latest snapshot to another instance for reporting purpose,
but I'm wondering if it is possible to automate this so I can restore the snapshots daily?

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule the restoration CLI command to get executed on particular event or at particular time.

```
aws rds restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot --db-instance-identifier mynewdbinstance --db-snapshot-identifier mydbsnapshot
```